# Mark all negative values of all variables as missing in SPSS

Tags: spss

How can I mark all negative values of all variables as missing in SPSS? I have a dataset of more then 300 variables but none of the have missing values defined, but for all of them -1 and -2 should be treated as missing values. Is there a better way than to do it by hand for every variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really mean all values <= -1 and all variables, you can use a missing range, like this:

```
missing values all (lo thru -1).
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is

```
mis val v1 to v399 ((-2),(-1)).
```